# New post outside wordpress via XML-RPC with "Send Trackback To" field

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I want to create new post on my wordpress blog via XML-RPC.

Problem:
I want to send Trackback URLs along with new post, just like we put URLs in wordpress panel (space separated) in Send Trackback to input box:

[image]

My code until now is:

```html
$content = array( 
    'title'=>$title, 
    'description'=>$body, 
    'mt_allow_comments'=>0, // 1 to allow comments 
    'mt_allow_pings'=>0, // 1 to allow trackbacks 
    'post_type'=>'post', 
    'mt_keywords'=>$keywords, 
    'categories'=>array($category),
    'wp_post_thumbnail' =>  $thumbnail_id 
);
```

Comment: Please help regarding this issue